# Dynamic Title for custom post types

Tags: functions, custom-header

I use a custom post called "abschreibungstabelle".

For all posts, I want to set the meta title dynamically:

"This is a test: " & the post title

Is there any easy way to do this:

Actually I use the following snippet in my header:

```
<title>
        <?php if ( is_plugin_inactive('wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php') ) {
               bloginfo( 'name' );
              } ?> <?php wp_title("|", true); ?>
</title>
```

The result is "post title" | my blog

Thank you, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use something like this in my `header.php`:

```
<title> 
<?php 
    if(is_front_page())
        echo "Front Page Title";
    else if(is_404())
        echo "Page Not Found";
    else
        the_title();
    echo ' | '.get_bloginfo('name');  
?>
</title>
```

Check out [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) for more information.

---

As a Function() :

`functions.php`

```
function setTitle(){
    global $post;

    $title = get_the_title();
    $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );

    if(is_tax())
        $title = $term->name;
    else if(is_search())
        $title = "Search";
    else if(is_404())
        $title = "Page Not Found";


    if(is_singular('customCPT')){
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'customCPT' ); 
        $term = array_pop($terms);
        $title = $term->name.' '.$title;
    }

    echo $title.'  |  '.get_bloginfo('name');
}
```

Then in your `header.php`

```
<title><?php setTitle(); ?></title>
```